# How to run kernel in debug mode and wait for KGDB with Virtualbox and Kali Linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, virtualbox, kgdb

I am trying to debug a Linux kernel using `Virtualbox`, but I cannot get it working.

Here is what I've done.

1. Compile Kernel with the following configuration

   ```
   CONFIG_HAVE_ARCH_KGDB=y   
   CONFIG_KGDB=y  
   CONFIG_KGDB_SERIAL_CONSOLE=y  
   CONFIG_KGDB_TESTS=y   
   CONFIG_KGDB_TESTS_ON_BOOT=y
   CONFIG_KGDB_TESTS_BOOT_STRING="V1F100"  
   CONFIG_KGDB_LOW_LEVEL_TRAP=y  
   CONFIG_KGDB_KDB=y  
   CONFIG_KDB_DEFAULT_ENABLE=0x1  
   CONFIG_KDB_KEYBOARD=y
   CONFIG_KDB_CONTINUE_CATASTROPHIC=0  
   CONFIG_ARCH_HAS_UBSAN_SANITIZE_ALL=y
   ```
2. Install the compiled kernel.
3. Add boot arguments

   ```
    kgdbwait kgdboc=ttyS1,115200
   ```

And it doesn't wait for `KGDB`. But when I try just to use a serial port to get the boot process output using `console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200` it works.

Kernel is `Linux/x86 4.9.16 Kernel` (Kali linux).

Comment: Here is a minimal self-contained QEMU + Buildroot setup that just worked for me:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004616/how-to-debug-the-linux-kernel-with-qemu-and-kgdb Maybe you can use that to diff out what is wrong, or use QEMU instead.